# Not sure how to handle "doctor" - as an honorific or as a noun

Tags: titles, honorifics

I understand that "doctor" would typically only be capitalized when referring to a specific person with that title, and otherwise is a regular old noun without capitalization.

Would its use in the following sentence be capitalized or not? I feel like it's incorrect to be in lowercase - or maybe it should be in italics?

- "I haven’t had the title of doctor taken from me, but I have a feeling it is forthcoming."

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Blue Book](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/capitalization/when-to-capitalize-peoples-titles/), you should only capitalize the title when you are addressing the person or using them to refer to a specific person who holds the title.

Your sentence is correct

More examples on capitalization in this [nice summary](https://cairn.edu/documents/2016/10/writing-lab-capitalization-rules.pdf/)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the greyer areas. Looking through the results for a Google search for "holds the title doctor" does not turn up a lot of results, but

(1) as far as I've checked, almost all of those results where 'doctor' is part of a more explicit title have 'doctor' capitalised:

- ... holds the title Doctor of Science ...
- ... holds the title Doctor of Jurisprudence ...
- ... holds the title Doctor of Chiropractic ...
- ... holds the title Doctor Honoris Causa from Blaise Pascal University ...

(amongst others) while

(2) most of the few examples I've found where 'doctor' is stand-alone use lower case, for example:

- any audiologist who holds the title doctor has earned a clinical doctorate in audiology [[American Academy of Audiology](https://audiology-web.s3.amazonaws.com/migrated/Use%20of%20the%20Term%20Doctor.pdf_53a2a10c175445.27939132.pdf)]
- As above your passport doesn't have a Dr field, it says 'holds the title doctor' on the official observations. [[Reddit; Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22holds+the+title+doctor%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=w-BWYanTDNW78gLxhLKwDg&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjpwOq4_qjzAhXVnVwKHXGCDOY4FBDy0wN6BAgBEDc&biw=1680&bih=939&dpr=1)]

Note that none of the above uses italicisation, which (with capitalisation) would have been my choice for your example sentence until a few years ago. And inverted commas (and quite possibly no 'of') would have been unsurprising in the not too distant past. This remains a style choice, but it's usually best to adopt the most usual practice in these matters.